# I want to paste stickers into to my TextField and to show the stickers beside the emojis

Tags: flutter

On one hand, I desire the ability to paste stickers into my TextField. While images are already functional, when attempting to copy an image from my pictures and convert it into a sticker, I do not receive the option to paste it into my TextField.

```
TextField(
              contentInsertionConfiguration: ContentInsertionConfiguration(
                onContentInserted: (_) {},
                allowedMimeTypes: ['*'],
              ),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Enter your name',
              ),
            ),
```

The second issue pertains to having stickers appear alongside emojis:
[Random App Where the stickers are displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zievq.jpg)

However, in my Flutter app, I do not encounter this keyboard layout, as shown in
[my app in flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7ai7.jpg)